# Changes in IBM Bluemix API that introduced potential bug

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, watson

We successfully used IBM Bluemix Speech-to-text API for almost a year. However, API suddenly stopped working for us. The reported error was that word_alternatives_threshold could not be None. This contradicts to documentation. In any case, we set  word_alternatives_threshold and received another error right away. This time, API reported that “keywords_threshold” was not defined. This also contradicts to the current documentation. If we set “keywords_threshold”, then we are asked to set keywords list, that we don't really need for our application. Setting keyword list gives another error that list is empty.
Were any changes introduced to API?

Update: Removing options from input fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi Ram, yes, there are some changes to the way parameter values are checked. The value of 'word_alternatives_threshold' needs to be in the interval [0,1], a floating point number. can you try that? It seems to be working for me: {'smart_formatting': True, 'continuous': True, 'interim_results': True, 'action': 'start', 'word_alternatives_threshold': 0.25, 'content-type': 'audio/l16; rate=44100'}

Comment: This answer does not work. Parameters like word_alternatives_threshold or keywords_threshold sometimes must be null or not defined for correct functionality. However, at this time, null or not defined parameters do not pass type checking.

Comment: Hi slav, can you just omit the parameter, if you are not setting it to any value, why passing it?